# how to migrate Ubuntu OS running on VMware on windows to virtualbox on a mac?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware-player

I have a windows machine, in which i have installed ubuntu OS(16.04) on VMWare.
Now i am using a Macbook pro, i want to move the entire files of the virtualised OS and the settings of the OS from the vmware on the windows to virtualbox on a mac!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to convert the virtual drive file to another format. google may help you with that. You could then create a new Virtual machine on virtual box and manually choose the drive file.

The host OS machine is not important there (windows mac or linux)

http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/